# Selberg's lemma proof using p-adic methods

Tags: abstract-algebra

Cassels in his book on local fields proves Selberg's lemma.
The argumentation starts like this:

> Let $G \subseteq \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ be finitely generated. Let
>   $C$ be the set of non-zero elements of $A$ and $A^{-1}$ when $A$ runs
>   through a set of generators of $G$ and let $K$ be the field generated
>   by $C$ over $\mathbb Q$.

1. Why $C$ has to be the set of non-zero elements? The group $G$ does not contain the zero matrix.
2. Does the field $K$ consist of $n \times n$ matrices? In this case one would expect to treat rational numbers $q \in \mathbb Q$ as diagonal matrices $q \cdot \mathrm{Id}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean Cassels? Casselman is a completely different chap.

I presume that $C$ is really the set of nonzero **entries** of the matrices
in $A$ and $A^{-1}$. The idea being to replace the field $k$ by $K$
which a finitely generated extension field of $\Bbb Q$.

I seem to remember the next stage is to embed $K$ into some $\Bbb Q_p$
(or a finite extension thereof).

Comment: Yes, the next step is to embed the extension of $\mathbb Q$ into some $\mathbb Q_p$ for $p \neq 2$ and then consider $H = \{g \in G : \alpha(g) \equiv \mathrm{Id} \mod p\}$.